# C++ multiple parameter packs grouped by name

Tags: c++, templates

I am currently trying to write some ECS in C++. Inside my ECS (Entity component system), I have a set of entities which all have a set of components. Like a position, rotation, etc.. What I want to do is implement a function which returns an iterator to iterate over the entities which fullfill a few requirements. These requirements are grouped into the following categories:

1. required
2. requires_one
3. excludes

Ideally, I would call the function like this:

```cpp
each<required<Position, Rotation>, requires_one<>, excludes<>>();
```

Depending on what is given inside the required, requires_one and exlcludes template, I would filter the entities while iterating over them.

Unfortunately I have never worked with parameter packs similar to this and would like to know where and how I should start with this.

My current code looks like this so far.

```cpp
template<typename... Types>
struct required{};

template<typename... Types>
struct requires_one{};

template<typename... Types>
struct excludes{};

template<required <> all, requires_one<> one, excludes<> excludes>
void ECS::each(){
    // ...
}
```

I simply don't know how to correctly write down the templates in this case.
I am very happy for any help or advice :)

Greetings
Finn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

common solution:

```cpp
template<typename...>
struct required;
template<typename...>
struct requires_one;
template<typename...>
struct excludes;

template<typename, typename, typename>
struct ECS_each_impl;
template<typename... RTypes, typename... ROTypes, typename... XTypes>
struct ECS_each_impl<required<RTypes...>, requires_one<ROTypes...>, excludes<XTypes...>>{
    void each(){
        // implementations...
    }
};

template<typename R, typename RO, typename X>
void each(){
    return ECS_each_impl<R, RO, X>::each();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Is there a possibility to set default values for RO and X?

Comment: @FinnEggers maybe you want `template<typename R, typename RO = requires_one<>, typename X = excludes<>>void each()`? actually you can do all you want in whether `each()` or `ECS_each_impl::each()`.